# Protobuf-net and chain interface serialization

Tags: c#, serialization, protobuf-net

I have a class with a member variable "IVariable" that needs to be serialized.  However, as you can probably tell by the name IVariable, it's an interface. Interface IVariable2 derives from IVariable, and Interface IVariable 3 derives from Ivariable2.  Finally, VariableBase, a fully implemented class derives from IVariable3. So my question is how would i be annotating this? Would it be like this?

```
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(7, typeof(IVariable2)]
public interface IVariable
{...}

[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(8, typeof(IVariable3)]
public interface IVariable2: IVariable
{...}

[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(9, typeof(VariableBase)]
public interface IVariable3: IVariable2
{...}

[ProtoContract]
public class VariableBase : IVariable3
{...}
```

Or would I have to add ALL derived types to IVariable? Also, sadly I can't get rid of IVariable (or 2 or 3) because there are some other types (that aren't serialized) that use the interfaces. Thanks.

Comment: Iirc, only concrete types are supported here, not interface chains

Comment: So, you're saying I should just be adding [ProtoInclude(9, typeof(VariableBase)] to IVariable?

Comment: I'd certainly give that a try, yes

Comment: Also as a side question, if there were multiple classes that derived from an interface, would you just put the ProtoInclude attribute for each of them?

Also, how would that work if I was using RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(Interface), true).AddSubType(...) method of doing it?